# When should I use `sudo` for `npm install -g cordova`?

Tags: cordova, npm, sudo, command-line-interface

I'm looking through the PhoneGap / Cordova CLI documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface and it recommends installing Cordova CLI as `sudo`

```
    $ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

However my linux co-workers have kicked my *ss for using sudo willy nilly, so does it definitely need it when installing the package or am I able to continue normal Cordova CLI use without it?

Thanks, DanC

Comment: I think you need sudo when you use the -g option of npm. You can try to run `npm install cordova` instead (so cordova will be available for your user) or if you have root access you can open a shell as root and run `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Thanks QuickFix, I just tried it and there's no apparent issues with just using `npm install -g cordova` .. odd (OSX 10.9.2)

Answer (score 0):

The cordova package is meant to be used as a command line utility, rather than a module you `require('cordova')` in other Node.js code.  The `-g` (or global install) option will install the cordova module at the location specified by [npm's prefix config setting](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html):

> The prefix config defaults to the location where node is installed. On most systems, this is `/usr/local`

You can view the current value of this setting with `npm config get prefix`.

Typically, using the global install option will add any shell scripts for the global module, like the `cordova` script, to a location visible with your shell's search `$PATH`.  This enables you to execute commands like `cordova create foo` without specifying the path to the `cordova` shell script.

I suspect your prefix path is something other than `/usr/local`, or your user account must have write privileges to the prefix folder.  Typical setups don't grant write privileges to `/usr/local` to regular users, thus the need for `sudo`.  I would personally prefer to use sudo to install things over granting write access to `/usr/local` to regular users.